# Rails start multiple processes that involve loops at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, docker, sh

In my Ruby on Rails project I have 3 workers. They are in `/lib/workers/worker_a.rb`, `/lib/workers/worker_b.rb`, and `/lib/workers/worker_c.rb`.

Worker A is defined like

```
class WorkerA
  def run!
      logger.info "Starting worker A"
      loop do
        begin
          do workerAWork
          sleep 1.5 if workerAWork
        rescue => e
          logger.error e
          sleep 3
        end
      end
    end
end
WorkerA.new.run! if __FILE__==$0
```

Worker B is defined very similarly:

```
class WorkerB
  def run!
      logger.info "Starting Worker B"
      loop do
        begin
          do workerBWork
          sleep 1.5 if workerBWork
        rescue => e
          logger.error e
          sleep 3
        end
      end
    end
end
WorkerA.new.run! if __FILE__==$0
```

Worker C again is defined like above.

All 3 workers are doing what the app needs them to do. However, during deployment using Docker, I would need to open 3 terminals and start each worker using `bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_a.rb`,`bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_b.rb`, `bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_c.rb`.

If I create a shell script that looks like

```
bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_a.rb
bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_b.rb
bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_c.rb
```

Only the first worker will start and the terminal will hang there as there is a loop. The loop will prevent workers B and C from starting.

Is there a way to write the script such that they can be started one after another?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort to reproduce what is essentially Sidekiq.

Comment: While you could use `bin/rails runner ./lib/workers/worker_a.rb &>/dev/null & disown` to run the commands in the background @anothermh is right - why reinvent the wheel and do it poorly?